# Ordering MySQL results (in PHP) with natural sort order

Tags: php, mysql, php-7.2

We have a MySQL table with lots of company names. The table collation is utf8_general_ci. The DB connection has a UTF8 charset during the handshake set.

To sort the company names in a natural sort order via PHP, we used a regular MySQL ORDER BY table.companyName (varchar 255) and an additonal PHP sort via usort() and strnatcasecmp().

```
    $select->order('table.companyName');

    [...]

    usort($records, function ($a, $b) {
        return strnatcasecmp($a['companyName'], $b['companyName']);
    });
```

This transformed a list of e.g:

```
["Company 1", "Crompany", "Cömpany", "Z Company", "ö Company"]
```

into

```
["Company 1", "Cömpany", "Crompany", "ö Company", "Z Company"]
```

for the last couple of years. The `usort()` change was added in 2016.

Currently, the output with both the `ORDER BY` clause and the `usort()` is all of a suddon not correctly sorted:

```
["Company 1", "Crompany", "Cömpany", "Z Company", "ö Company"]
```

Removing the `usort()`/`strnatcasecmp()` fixes the sort order back to

```
["Company 1", "Cömpany", "Crompany", "ö Company", "Z Company"].
```

I'm just not sure if I been missing any change lately to either MySQLs sort order algorithm or the `strnatcasecmp()` behaviour in PHP, possibly related to UTF8?

We're using PHP 7.2.22 and mysqld 5.7.27 (dev) or 5.7.26 (production).